# Smart Card Reader, can't read some cards

Tags: c#, smartcard

I have an application that is using an smart card reader for allowing the users to access parts of the system. On one location i have no issues. But another, which have an different type of card manufacturer has a lot of issues. It keeps getting an id of zero back. Then looking into the eventlog i saw this:
[image]
And this is the code:

```
 card.Connect(reader, SHARE.Shared, PROTOCOL.T0orT1);

 var apduGetID = new APDUCommand(0xFF, 0xCA, 0, 0, null, 4);
 var apduRespGetID = card.Transmit(apduGetID);
long cardId = BitConverter.ToUInt32(apduRespGetID.Data.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
```

the second problem is that then trying to debug the code, it works perfect, only then remove the breakpoint can i see the issue but not where. Can some one please help me?

P.S. i found this thread, but it does not work: https://superuser.com/questions/715688/smart-card-errors

**Update: Here are the Transmit class**

```
 public override APDUResponse Transmit(APDUCommand ApduCmd)
        {
            var RecvLength = (uint)(ApduCmd.Le + APDUResponse.SW_LENGTH);
            byte[] ApduBuffer;
            var ApduResponse = new byte[ApduCmd.Le + APDUResponse.SW_LENGTH];
            var ioRequest = new SCard_IO_Request
            {
                m_dwProtocol = m_nProtocol,
                m_cbPciLength = 8
            };

            // Build the command APDU
            if (ApduCmd.Data == null)
            {
                ApduBuffer = new byte[APDUCommand.APDU_MIN_LENGTH + ((ApduCmd.Le != 0) ? 1 : 0)];

                if (ApduCmd.Le != 0)
                {
                    ApduBuffer[4] = ApduCmd.Le;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ApduBuffer = new byte[APDUCommand.APDU_MIN_LENGTH + 1 + ApduCmd.Data.Length];

                for (var nI = 0; nI < ApduCmd.Data.Length; nI++)
                {
                    ApduBuffer[APDUCommand.APDU_MIN_LENGTH + 1 + nI] = ApduCmd.Data[nI];
                }

                ApduBuffer[APDUCommand.APDU_MIN_LENGTH] = (byte)ApduCmd.Data.Length;
            }

            ApduBuffer[0] = ApduCmd.Class;
            ApduBuffer[1] = ApduCmd.Ins;
            ApduBuffer[2] = ApduCmd.P1;
            ApduBuffer[3] = ApduCmd.P2;

            m_nLastError = SCardTransmit(m_hCard, ref ioRequest, ApduBuffer, (uint)ApduBuffer.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ApduResponse, out RecvLength);

            if (m_nLastError != 0)
            {
                var msg = "SCardTransmit error: " + m_nLastError;
                throw new SmartCardException(msg, m_nLastError);
            }

            var apduData = new byte[RecvLength];

            for (var nI = 0; nI < RecvLength; nI++)
            {
                apduData[nI] = ApduResponse[nI];
            }

            return new APDUResponse(apduData);
        }
```

Update 2: I have also tried with to put some Thread.Sleep()

Comment: What does `card.Transmit` do? That is, what is the actual response from the card-reader or card? What kind of card are you working with?

Comment: Can you put some delay between your command and try again? may the reader or the card is not as fast as your program running time?

Comment: Do you yourself wrote the program that is installed on the smart cards? can you send `00A404000004` to both kind of cards and add the response of the cards to the question? (Use this tool to send APDU commands to the cards : https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki)

Comment: Temporarily disable all the firewalls and anti-virus applications, then check the issue again.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Hi. @Hut8 I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Hi @Aishwarya_Shiva I have just tried it without any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check that on the second machine you have all the up-to-date drivers of the smart card. Also, sometimes it helps to replace the driver which is provided by the manufacturer with "Microsoft WUDF driver" - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653571(v=vs.85).aspx

Please note, that you have two type of devices detected by the OS when you plug it in - the smart card enumerator device (smart card reader) and the smart card (sometimes called the smart card container) itself. One smart card reader can contain several smart cards.

Example of the smart card which driver was forcefully replaced with Microsoft WUDF to make the client application (iBank2) work:

[image: four smart cards WUDF type]

The four smart card drivers have been forcefully replaced with basic Microsoft driver to make the application work.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the other system does not take your smart card,just check the `BIOS` settings for smartcard.There is an option to disable/enable them in some systems.